# Create a folder without read-only using c#

Tags: c#, .net, directory

I have tried several approaches and I don't understand why, the read-only property is not removed whatsoever.I have a directory which has several .xls files and I used directory.getfilename to copy files from this directory to a newly created directory. But when I try to access the new directory with copied .xls files, it says file might be read-only or encrypted. So instead I tried a mock up creating a folder and see that code does not remove read-only.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\hello");
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\hello");
    di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
}
```

I tried several other approaches but failed. Any idea why?

Comment: I read through the post and it makes sense. but though the files inside are normal, I still keep getting that same error. The directory "dirname" is either read-only or encrypted.

Comment: As far as I can tell the answer actually said that Windows not .NET was the reason the for the exception and you can actually set the attribute you just have to use Directory.SetAccessControl to set the value, it just said .NET doesn't honor the attribute but it can be set.

Comment: Update: I read the same file in the same location and wrote to it and copied it to another location with no problem. So interop cannot read the file. This further proves that read-only (what I was assuming earlier) is not an issue.